# In controller in admin of my component, i want to load a model from com_plugins

Tags: extensions, joomla-4

In my controller of my component, i want to load the model : PluginModel from Joomla\Component\Plugins\Administrator\Model\PluginModel;

In my controller the getModel method return just false, this is my controller :

```
use Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\AdminController;

class PluginsController extends AdminController
{
    public function __construct($config = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($config);
    }

    public function publish()
    {
        $model = $this->getModel();
    }

    public function getModel($name = 'Plugin', $prefix = 'Administrator', $config = ['ignore_request' => true])
    {
        return parent::getModel($name, $prefix, $config);
    }
}
```

By using this way it works on J!3.9.x but on J!4.0, the $model = $this->getModel(); just return false

How to load the model ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Joomla4 has a different approach.
This is how you can call other component's Model:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

$app = Factory::getApplication();
$model = $app->bootComponent('com_plugins')->getMVCFactory()->createModel('Plugin', 'Administrator', ['ignore_request' => true]);
```

or, the legacy way is also working about a year ago in Joomla4:

```
JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_plugins/models', 'PluginModel');
$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Plugin', 'PluginsModel', ['ignore_request' => true]);
```

I did not test that, but theoretically your code also should work if you add the model path and change the `$prefix` like:

```
public function getModel($name = 'Plugin', $prefix = 'PluginsModel', $config = ['ignore_request' => true])
{
    JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_plugins/models', 'PluginModel');
    return parent::getModel($name, $prefix, $config);
}
```

Comment: I had tested with the first method and it works for me